# woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook parameters

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to ask if what are the parameters inside create_function specially the numbers 5 and 2?

I have not found a clear explanation on their documentation.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', create_function('', 'echo "<a href=\"#\">ADD TO CART</a>";'), 5, 2);
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think the 5 is the priority and 2 refers that the functions expects 2 parametrs. and FYI 5 and 2 are not inside create_function().

Comment: That's not a piece of code from WooCommerce. I'm 99% sure they don't have any anonymous functions. [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) is explained in the Codex.